# ONNX Runtime memory arena, reuse, and pattern

Tags: memory, memory-management, onnx, onnxruntime, tf2onnx

As described in [Python API Doc](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/api/python/api_summary.html#onnxruntime.SessionOptions.enable_cpu_mem_arena), there are some params in onnxruntime session options coressponding to memory configurations such as:

- enable_cpu_mem_arena
- enable_mem_usage
- enable_mem_pattern

There are some descriptions for them but I can not understaned their usage and the technical concepts behind them precisely.

Can anyone give me some clarity about these parameters?

Answer (score 1):

**enable_mem_pattern**

Enable the memory pattern optimization.

The idea is if the input shapes are the same, we could trace the internal memory allocation and generate a memory pattern for future request. So next time we could just do one allocation with a big chunk for all the internal memory allocation.

Note
Memory pattern optimization is only available when Sequential Execution mode is enabled (see OrtApi::SetSessionExecutionMode)

**enable_cpu_mem_arena**

Enable the memory arena on CPU.

Arena may pre-allocate memory for future usage.

Info based on the api doc:
https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/api/c/struct_ort_api.html